# LAST_DAY function in mysql is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I am using LAST_DAY() function to get last day of values from each month for each customer in mysql.
I am using mysql 8.0 version.
Could anyone please help me with this.
Sample table example:

[image]

sample code:

```
select customer_id, LAST_DAY(txn_date) AS months, txn_type, txn_amount 
   from data_bank.customer_transactions
   group by customer_id, months
   order by customer_id
```

From the above code this is the results I have obtained :

[image]

Expected results:

```
customer_id   months     txn_type  txn_amount
      1      2020-01-31   deposit       312
      1      2020-03-31   purchase      664
```

Comment: The results that you get are correct. You missed the column `months` in your expecte results.

Comment: Add `max(txn_date)` to list of values.

Comment: Take some time to read about `LAST_DAY()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day

Comment: I have already read the last_day () documentation, if you see the expected results which I want is different. @forpas

Comment: The difference between the results that you get and your expected results: the column `txn_amount` which is arbitrary because you did not group by that or did not aggregate. This has nothing to do with LAST_DAY()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that because you group by the last day of the month, it will return the latest row's values for the other columns. That's not the case. The values returned in one column have ***nothing*** to do with the functions applied to other columns.

Read this:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Then use something like this to return the latest row per calendar month...

```
WITH
  partitioned AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY customer_id, LAST_DAY(txn_date) 
            ORDER BY txn_date DESC
      )
        AS month_row_id
  FROM
    data_bank.customer_transactions
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  partitioned
WHERE
  month_row_id = 1
```